# Java String to Date on POST Method

Tags: java

I'm trying  parse String data to Date.Json get the sending string data for post method.But i have an error.

```
 private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
private Date date;
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON+ ";charset=UTF-8")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public TravelDTO save(TravelDTO dto) {
    dto.setUser(userService.get(dto.getUser().getUserID()));
     dto.setTravelStart(simpleDateFormat.parse(data));
    return travelService.save(dto);
}
```

error:

```
 parse
(java.lang.String)
in DateFormat cannot be applied
to
(java.util.Date)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing wrong type to `parse` method - it requires `String`, but `data` variable has `java.util.Date` type.

But you are getting confused with `SimpleDateFormat` class. It doesn't modify Date itself, it's used to parse a String to Date type when used with `parse` method, or just changes its String representation when used with `format` method.
So, if you need to pass a `String` to `dto.setTravelStart(.)` - use `simpleDateFormat.format(data)`. If you need to pass `Date` instance - pass `data` object durectly.

Comment: no,i just need incoming string data to database in dd/MM/yyyy format. Because string format is "dd/MM/yyyy" but Date does not accept this

Comment: Then my answer should help

Comment: your advice is not worked."Unhandled exception: java.text.ParseException"

Comment: This means that `data` variable can't be parsed with your simpleDateFormat. Post its value here

Comment: I don't understand everything look good but i have "parse
(java.lang.String)
in DateFormat cannot be applied
to
(com.travelSystem.dto.TravelDTO)
"

Comment: if i try .format function error = "setTravelStart
(java.util.Date)
in TravelDTO cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String)
 "  .It's my data = travelService.get(dto.getTravelStart()) and it's Date format.